# From Python Script Run Another Python Scrip Without Conslole Appearing

Tags: python, user-interface, console, os.system

Most of it's explained in the title. Basically I want to open another Python program from within a Python Program but without a console appearing in the background.
Here is the line of code I'm using at the moment:

```
os.system('Connect1.pyw')
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Treat it like a module** You can do `import pythonefile.py`
**2.** You can use the exec command `execfile('file.py')`

Comment: ImportError: No module named pythonefile.py